# Range-based for statement definition redundancy

Tags: c++, for-loop, range, c++11, argument-dependent-lookup

Looking at n3092, in §6.5.4 we find the equivalency for a range-based for loop. It then goes on to say what `__begin` and `__end` are equal to. It differentiates between arrays and other types, and I find this redundant (aka confusing).

It says for arrays types that `__begin` and `__end` are what you expect: a pointer to the first and a pointer to one-past the end. Then for other types, `__begin` and `__end` are equal to `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, with ADL. Namespace `std` is associated, in order to find the `std::begin` and `std::end` defined in `<iterator>`, §24.6.5.

However, if we look at the definition of `std::begin` and `std::end`, they are both defined for arrays as well as container types. And the array versions do exactly the same as above: pointer to the first, pointer to one-past the end.

Why is there a need to differentiate arrays from other types, when the definition given for other types would work just as well, finding `std::begin` and `std::end`?

---

<sub>Some abridged quotes for convenience:</sub>

> #### §6.5.4 The range-based `for` statement
>
> — if _RangeT is an array type, begin-expr and end-expr are __range and __range + __bound, respectively, where __bound is the array bound. If _RangeT is an array of unknown size or an array of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed.
>
> — otherwise, begin-expr and end-expr are begin(__range) and end(__range), respectively, where begin and end are looked up with argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2). For the purposes of this name lookup, namespace std is an associated namespace.

> #### §24.6.5 range access
>
> ```
> template <class T, size_t N> T* begin(T (&array)[N]);
> ```
>
> Returns: array.
>
> ```
> template <class T, size_t N> T* end(T (&array)[N]);
> ```
>
> Returns: array + N.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This avoids a corner-case with ADL:

```
namespace other {
  struct T {};
  int begin(T*) { return 42; }
}

other::T a[3];
for (auto v : a) {}
```

Because ADL finds other::begin when calling `begin(a)`, the equivalent code would break causing a confusing compile error (along the lines of "can't compare int to other::T*" as `end(a)` would return a T*) or different behavior (if other::end was defined and did something likewise unexpected).

Comment: Nice :) It also enables users to use the loop without including any headers first.

Comment: @Johannes: Shouldn't be a problem; if you include a container header, you get begin & end too, according to 24.6.5 in the FCD.  Types not in the stdlib should make any custom begin/end available similarly, so only in exceedingly rare cases would it be required.  (But, damn, that's a major annoyance if you run into it.)

Comment: @Roger iterating over an `int[]` is such a case where a header would be required then, i mean.

Comment: One line summary: looking for `begin` and `end` via ADL may not find `std::begin` and `std::end`.