# Subtracting map iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary

I have a program where I have two `std::map` iterators say `left` and `right` respectively. I want to find the number of elements in the range `[left,right].`

I naively did something like this : `int len = right - left`. I thought it would be just fine but it [gave me an error](http://ideone.com/Ie9t1v)

Then I discovered `distance(left, right)` method thank to a post on Stack Overflow but unfortunately it has a linear time complexity.

Is it possible to get an `O(1)` solution for this?

Comment: Nope, `std::distance` is the best you'll do. If you really need an `O(1)` solution to this, try [boost::flatmap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/container/flat_map.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible to get an O(1) solution for this?

No.  a `std::map` has a [*BidirectionalIterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator).  A *BidirectionalIterator* does not support random access and can only be incremented or decremented.  That means if you want to move 5 positions forward you have to call `++iterator_name` 5 times.  If you need random access then you will need to pick a container that supports that like a `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: *if you want to move 5 positions forward you have to call ++iterator_name 5 times.*: or maybe using [`std::advance(iterator, 5)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance)

Comment: @JeJo Which is an abstraction of that.  I didn't bring it up as no mater what helper you do, it is an O(N) operation.

Comment: Yes, sure. I mean instead of calling `++iter, ++iter,...5 times`, one can simplify by `std::advance`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `policy based data structure` which is compiler specific. More details can be found [on this codeforces post](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080) The same can be used for set as well.