# Confusion in concept of iterator in map in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator

Suppose I have a map named `m` and an iterator `i` for the map. Presently I am visualising a map iterator as an array index and I want to implement a code like the one given below:

```
for(auto i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++)  { 
  auto l = i - 1;  // error type 1
  auto r = i + 1;  // error type 1
  while(l >= m.begin() && r < m.end()) { // error type 2
    // ...
    r++;
    l--;
  }
}
```

Now, I have got some questions which has been confusing me a bit.

For the error type 1 stated in the code, incrementing or decrementing the iterator value gives error, but the similar operation done within the loop (I mean to say `i++`) gives no error.

For error type 2, why does comparing two iterators (`l >= m.begin()`), straight up give error, but doing the similar operation in a loop does not give error?

And finally, how could I make this code work on the lines of how an array index works using this map? I hope you can understand what I am trying to implement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting map iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43680836/subtracting-map-iterators)

Comment: An iterator is like a pointer to an element, but it is in fact an *object*, it has overloaded operators ++ and -- but not + or -. And please, one question at a time, if possible.

Comment: `std::map` (assuming that's what you are using) uses a bidirectional iterator. This is a iterator supporting increment `it++` and de-increment `it--` but no arbitrary offset `it + n`. For that you would need a random access iterator.

Comment: if you need indexes sometimes it is better to use an index rather than iterators. However, if you want to use an array index, why dont you use an array in the first place?

Comment: Actually I need the help of frequency of each element in an array and do some bunch of stuff with them. So, I decided to go on with a map.

Comment: My big worry is that you ascribe any meaning to begin()-1. What are you expecting that would be?

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon If I iterate through the map by using decrement `it--` , is there any way to check the boundary condition?

Comment: @7k7 yes, you test for equality with `m.begin()`

Comment: @7k7 If you are iterating through a `std::map` backwards, it is recommended to use `reverse_iterator`. And you can test the boundary condition with `m.rbegin()`.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator for `std::map` is defined by standard as [Bidirectional Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). This type of iterators can be incremented(operator `++`) and decremented (operator `--`), but you can't perform mathematical operations on them (mostly because it would take O(n) time rather than O(1))

And again, for error 2, bidirectional iterator does not overload `<` operator (nor other variations), as it doesn't make sense to have compare operator with O(n) complexity. They are overloaded in random access iterators at the lowest.

To achieve what you wanted, your code can look like this:

```
#include <iterator> /for std::next() and std::prev()
for(auto i = m.begin; i != m.end(); ++i)
{
    auto l = i;
    auto r = i;
    if (i != m.begin())
        l = std::prev(i);
    if (i != m.end())
        r = std::next(i);
    while (l != m.begin() && r != m.end())
    {
        //make sure you don't use r if it's equal to m.end()
        --l;
        ++r;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Map is an `associative container`. The following containers are defined in the current revision of the C++ standard with `associative container`: set, map, multiset, multimap.

`Associative Containers` support `bidirectional iterators`. `Bidirectional iterators` are iterators that can be used to access the sequence of elements in a range in both directions (towards the end and towards the beginning). They are similar to `forward iterators`, except that they can move in the backward direction also, unlike the `forward iterators`, which can move only in forward direction.

`Bidirectional iterators` support following operations:

- Is default-constructible, copy-constructible, copy-assignable and
  destructible `X a;` `X b(a);` `b = a;`
- Can be compared for equivalence using the equality/inequality
  operators (meaningful when both iterator values iterate over the same
  underlying sequence).    `a == b`     `a != b`
- Can be dereferenced as an rvalue (if in a dereferenceable state).
  `*a` `a->m`
- For mutable iterators (non-constant iterators): Can be dereferenced
  as an lvalue (if in a dereferenceable state).    `*a = t`
- Can be incremented (if in a dereferenceable state). The result is
  either also dereferenceable or a past-the-end iterator. Two iterators
  that compare equal, keep comparing equal after being both increased.
  `++a` `a++` `*a++`
- Can be decremented (if a dereferenceable iterator value precedes it).
  `--a` `a--` `*a--`

**So, + and - is not defined for it, which leads to the error1.

And so is >=, <=, >, < not defined for it, which leads to error2.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is iterator doesn't work like array indices. The elements of `map` will be stored at different locations in memory and there is no guarantee that the between elements `i` and `j` in map, if `i` comes before `j`, then it will be stored in memory just before `j`. **The values are not stored at consecutive locations in memory in case of map**.

The `++` operator is overloaded for iterators and it will give the proper location of the next element.

Also, if you consider the points above, then comparing two iterators makes no sense because the fact that one iterator comes after another doesn't give us any important information regarding the corresponding values that will be accessed using these two iterators.

Answer (score 0):

there are different iterator categories/concepts: [Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator), [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator), [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) and [ContiguousIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ContiguousIterator). They differ in available operations. Simple iterators only support step forward (`operator ++`), dereference (`operator *`) and inequality comparison (`operator !=`). This is the required minimum for `range-based for` loop. `std::map::iterator` is `BidirectionalIterator` - it doesn't support arithmetic or comparison operators.

Comment: Okay I understood that `++` operator yields the just next iterator in the map. But is there a way to find the previous iterator and check the boundary condition while iterating in the backward direction?

Comment: @7k7, there are two approaches: 1. (simple) use `--` and check against `begin()` and 2. (elegant) use `std::make_reverse_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the x-y problem: I want to do "this", I wrote code that does "that"

So I presume you really do want to have access to the previous element in the map, and the next element. I presume you only want this when those 2 elements are "good"

You could recast your loop to cascade the knowledge of the 3 neighbouring iterators:

```
for(auto r = m.begin(), e= m.end(), i= e,  l= e; r != e; l =i, i =r, r++)  
{ 
    if (l != e)
    {
         // All 3 iterators are good here
    }
}
```