# How to get current iterator in lambda operation

Tags: c++, algorithm, foreach, lambda, iterator

How can I solve the following situation, for any container-type which can use the for_each function -> for a vector this would be easy, because I could add a variable outside the call and give it as a reference parameter and increment it in the lambda function. So how can I get the current iterator in the lambda function?

```
std::for_each(container.begin(), container.end(), []() {
            //do-something and get the current iterator
});
```

Comment: I think this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752019/how-to-get-the-index-of-a-value-in-a-vector-using-for-each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do not call `std::for_each()` but use loop:

```
auto lambda = []( auto iter ) {}
for( auto it = container.begin(); it != container.end(); ++it ) lambda( it );
```

if you prefer you can write an algo around it:

```
template< class InputIt, class UnaryFunction >
UnaryFunction for_each_iter( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f )
{
    while( first != last ) f(first++);
    return f;
}
```

Comment: `UnaryFunction` cannot be `void` or it wouldn't be callable, thus you need a `return`. Also, even though iterators *should* be cheaply copyable, there's no reason to depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function:

```
template<class InputIt, class UnaryFunction>
UnaryFunction for_each_it(InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryFunction f) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) (void) f(first);
    return f;
}
```