# How to use std::sort to sort an array in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

How to use standard template library `std::sort()` to sort an array declared as 
`int v[2000]`;

Does C++ provide some function that can get the begin and end index of an array?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In C++0x/11 we get [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) which are overloaded for arrays:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
  int v[2000];
  std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
}
```

If you don't have access to C++0x, it isn't hard to write them yourself:

```
// for container with nested typedefs, non-const version
template<class Cont>
typename Cont::iterator begin(Cont& c){
  return c.begin();
}

template<class Cont>
typename Cont::iterator end(Cont& c){
  return c.end();
}

// const version
template<class Cont>
typename Cont::const_iterator begin(Cont const& c){
  return c.begin();
}

template<class Cont>
typename Cont::const_iterator end(Cont const& c){
  return c.end();
}

// overloads for C style arrays
template<class T, std::size_t N>
T* begin(T (&arr)[N]){
  return &arr[0];
}

template<class T, std::size_t N>
T* end(T (&arr)[N]){
  return arr + N;
}
```

Comment: Are `std::begin()` and `std::end()` C++1x additions?  They're very nice -- should have been this way from the outset, it would have made a lot of algorithms more generic!

Comment: `std::begin()` and `std::end()` aren't a part of the current C++ Standard, but you can use `boost::begin()` and `boost::end()`.

Comment: I believe they are C++98/03, but I'm on my iPod right now and I can't remember in which header they reside... Edit: Seems I'm worng, but it isn't hard to write those yourself. Gonna edit...

Comment: @j_random_hacker, new to me too.  Most google hits for std::begin/end point back to SO, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648878/range-based-for-statement-definition-redundancy

Comment: Edited accordingly to the comments.

Comment: Just a reminder: long before they were to proposed for C++11, most of us had such a `begin` and `end` function in our personal tool kits.  Before C++11, however, they had a serios disadvantage: they didn't result in an integral constant expression.  So depending on the specific needs, we'd use them, or a macro which did the division of the two `sizeof`.

Comment: @James: Another important factor in C++11 is `decltype`. That way, you only need one template each for `begin` and `end` to support any range that has these member functions.

Comment: @Xeo I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  `decltype` certainly simplifies certain uses, but I don't see what it has to do with the free `begin` and `end` functions.  (And you really should have two each of them, one for C style arrays, and another for containers, with automatic discrimination, so you can use them in templates, without knowing whether the type is a container or a C style array.)

Comment: @James: D'oh, disregard that comment. I totally forgot about the nested typedefs in the STL container... Added the simple templates now. :)

Comment: @Xeo Is there any particular reason you wrote `&arr[0]` instead of `arr`? Is not the name of an array synonymous with the address of the 0th element of an array? This is in regards to your begin overload for C style arrays.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: I just like being explicit.

Answer (score 86):

```
#include <algorithm>
static const size_t v_size = 2000;
int v[v_size];
// Fill the array by values
std::sort(v, v + v_size);
```

In [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
std::array<int, 2000> v;
// Fill the array by values
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Comment: +1: Correct but very brittle. If the sort is not near the declaration this can easily be broken during maintenance.

Comment: @Martin: true. That's why I prefer to use `std::vector`. My code would be: `std::vector<int> v(2000); std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );`

Comment: Of course, using literal array sizes is always dangerous, as in the example. But there is nothing wrong with putting the array size into a 'const int'.

Answer (score 35):

If you don't know the size, you can use:

```
std::sort(v, v + sizeof v / sizeof v[0]);
```

Even if you do know the size, it's a good idea to code it this way as it will reduce the possibility of a bug if the array size is changed later.

Comment: If it is statically allocated, he should know the size, because the compiler knows. But this is better coding practice.

Comment: Since you are writting future proof code, instead of using the `sizeof x/sizeof *x` trick you should use a safer template: `template <typename T, int N> int array_size( T (&)[N] ) { return N; }`, as that will fail if instead of an array you pass a pointer. It can be converted into a compile time constant if needed, but it becomes a little too hard to read in a comment.

Comment: @David: Good idea, but an even better (and dare I say The Right) way is to define `begin()` and `end()` function templates that are specialised for all common container types, including arrays, and use them instead.  Xeo's answer made me think these had already been added to C++, now it seems they haven't...  I'll see what else people have to say and then update.

Comment: :) I have a small utility header that has a few bits like this, including `begin`, `end`, `size`, `STATIC_SIZE` (macro that returns a compile time constant with the size), but to be honest, I hardly ever use that outside of small code samples.

Comment: The size of an array can be received by `std::extent<decltype(v)>::value` in C++11

Answer (score 21):

You can sort it `std::sort(v, v + 2000)`

Comment: +1: Correct but very brittle. If the sort is not near the declaration this can easily be broken during maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

**you can use sort() in C++ STL.  sort() function Syntax :**

```
 sort(array_name, array_name+size)      

 So you use  sort(v, v+2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is as simple as that ... C++ is providing you a function in STL (Standard Template Library) called `sort` which runs 20% to 50% faster than the hand-coded quick-sort.

Here is the sample code for it's usage:

```
std::sort(arr, arr + size);
```

Answer (score 2):

sort() can be applied on both array and vector in C++ to sort or re-arrange elements .

**1. C++ sort() in case of a vector:**

// importing vector, algorithm & iostream

using namespace std;

int main()
{

vector v = {5,4,3,2,8}; // depending on your vector size

sort(v.begin(), v.end());

cout<<v[1];    //testing the sorted element positions by printing

return 0;

}

**2. C++ sort() in case of an array:**

// including algorithm & iostream

using namespace std;

int main() {

int array[] = {10, 35, 85};   // array size 2000 in your case
int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

sort(array, array+3);

cout<<array[0];

return 0;

}

**Note: Both the above snippets were tested with modern C++ versions (11,17 & 20) before posting here .**

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    int a[5];
    int temp = 0;
    cout << "Enter Values: " << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if(a[i] > a[j])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
    cout << "Asending Series" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            if(a[i] < a[j])
            {
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
    cout << "Desending Series" << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << endl;
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. OP asked how to use the `std::sort` algorithm, not how to implement a sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

```
//sort by number
bool sortByStartNumber(Player &p1, Player &p2) {
    return p1.getStartNumber() < p2.getStartNumber();
}
//sort by string
bool sortByName(Player &p1, Player &p2) {
    string s1 = p1.getFullName();
    string s2 = p2.getFullName();
    return s1.compare(s2) == -1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers that provide only code, without any explanation, are generally frowned upon, especially when a) there are many answers already provided, and b) an answer has already been accepted. Please elaborate on why your solution is different and/or better from the 12 that have already been posted.

Answer (score 1):

With the Ranges library that is coming in C++20, you can use

```
ranges::sort(arr);
```

directly, where `arr` is a builtin array.

Answer (score 0):

sorting method without `std::sort`:

```
// sorting myArray ascending
int iTemp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j <= ARRAYSIZE; j++)
    {
        // for descending sort change '<' with '>'
        if (myArray[j] < myArray[i])
        {
            iTemp = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[j];
            myArray[j] = iTemp;
        }
    }
}
```

[Run](http://cpp.sh/52vsb) complete example:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl /* http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iostream */
#include <cstdlib>  // srand(), rand()      /* http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib */
#include <ctime>    // time()               /* http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ctime */


int main()
{
    const int ARRAYSIZE = 10;
    int myArray[ARRAYSIZE];

    // populate myArray with random numbers from 1 to 1000
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = rand()% 1000 + 1;
    }

    // print unsorted myArray
    std::cout << "unsorted myArray: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] -> " << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // sorting myArray ascending
    int iTemp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= ARRAYSIZE; j++)
        {
            // for descending sort change '<' with '>'
            if (myArray[j] < myArray[i])
            {
                iTemp = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = iTemp;
            }
        }
    }

    // print sorted myArray
    std::cout << "sorted myArray: " << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << i << "] -> " << myArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Really? You want to use a slow bubble sort instead of the standard library? Not only that, you have an off-by-one error causing UB.

Answer (score 0):

Use the C++ [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function:

```
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> v(2000);
  sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

C++ sorting using sort function

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

vector <int> v[100];

int main()
{
  sort(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Comment: This one Works on older version. I tried with this: `std::sort(arr, arr + arr_size)`

Comment: This doesn't work at all.  Not to say it is not C++.

Answer (score -2):

you can use,

```
 std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Comment: Hi, this question already seems to have a an broadly accepted answer. Can you explain how this is different?

Comment: Arrays don't have `begin` and `end` methods. You must be thinking of a `vector`.