# C++ Sorting an array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm following a set of beginner assignments I found on a forum for c++, but I'm totally stuck at a task now. 
The task is as follows:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes
>   eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ...,
>   Person 10) Once the data has been entered the program must analyze the
>   data and output which person ate the most pancakes for breakfast.
>
> ★ Modify the program so that it also outputs which person ate the
>   least number of pancakes for breakfast.
>
> ★★★★ Modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number
>   of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.

Now I've sorted out the original bit and the one star bit, however I chose to make it a bit more difficult for myself and not just go with "Person 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on, instead I've assigned names to the characters, and I print it out with a `switch`.
Here's my current code, I'd love some suggestions on how I could sort the array without messing with the order of the numbers in the array, as that would mess up my naming code I guess.

Here's my code, I know it's not the prettiest code out there but it's functional for now.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nMostPancakesName;
    int nLeastPancakesName;
    enum BreakfastNames
    {
        NED, // 0
        ARYA, // 1
        JON, // 2
        ROBB, // 3
        SANSA, // 4
        CATELYN, // 5
        BRAN, // 6
        THEON, // 7
        HODOR, // 8
        GHOST // 9
    };

    int anArray[10];
    cout << "Enter the number of pancakes Ned ate for breakfast: " << endl;
    cin >> anArray[NED];
    cout << "How many did Arya eat?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[ARYA];
    cout << "And Jon?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[JON];
    cout << "What about Robb?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[ROBB];
    cout << "Did Sansa have any?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[SANSA];
    cout << "Catelyn?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[CATELYN];
    cout << "Crippleboy aka Bran?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[BRAN];
    cout << "The traitor didn't get any, did he?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[THEON];
    cout << "Hodor?" << endl;
    cin >> anArray[HODOR];
    cout << "No pets at the dining table, Ghost." << endl;
    cin >> anArray[GHOST];

    int nMaxPancakes = 0;
    for (int nPancakes = 0; nPancakes < 10; nPancakes++)
        if (anArray[nPancakes] > nMaxPancakes)
        {
            nMostPancakesName = nPancakes;
            nMaxPancakes = anArray[nPancakes];
        }


    int nLeastPancakes = 100;
    for (int nPancakes2 = 0; nPancakes2 < 10; nPancakes2++)
        if (anArray[nPancakes2] < nLeastPancakes)
        {
            nLeastPancakesName = nPancakes2;
            nLeastPancakes = anArray[nPancakes2];
        }

        for (int nStartIndex = 0; nStartIndex < 10; nStartIndex++)
        {
            int nSmallestIndex = nStartIndex;

            for (int nCurrentIndex = nStartIndex + 1; nCurrentIndex < 10; nCurrentIndex++)
            {
                if (anArray[nCurrentIndex] < anArray[nSmallestIndex])
                    nSmallestIndex = nCurrentIndex;
            }


        }


    switch(nMostPancakesName)
    {
    case 0:
        cout << "Ned had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "Arya had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Jon had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Robb had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Sansa had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Catelyn had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "Bran had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        cout << "Theon had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 8:
        cout << "Hodor had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 9:
        cout << "Ghost had " << nMaxPancakes << endl;
        break;
    }

    switch(nLeastPancakesName)
    {
    case 0:
        cout << "Ned had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 1:
        cout << "Arya had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "Jon had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Robb had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Sansa had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 5:
        cout << "Catelyn had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 6:
        cout << "Bran had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 7:
        cout << "Theon had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 8:
        cout << "Hodor had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    case 9:
        cout << "Ghost had " << nLeastPancakes << endl;
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be an array? You can use a std::vector and sort() via <algorithm>.

Comment: You can also sort an array via <algorithm>, same way.

Comment: @C. Lang, then you would use a map, and answer all the questions with the same program.

Comment: See "How to use std::sort to sort an array in C++": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897319/how-to-use-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-in-c

Comment: @7stud: good point! I read the title and went to typing:( The vector part was because that's what everyone suggests when OP uses arrays. The one time I do it, I get caught sleepin'.

Comment: @C.Lang Well, it doesn't really, it was just the only way I knew how to achieve what the task asked for, so that's what I went for. Haven't come very far in the c++ class yet. I'll look into vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example. There are better way's to do this, but this should give you a basic idea of one of the way's to do this.

```
int score[10];
int ScoreCheck = 0;

// initalize the array "score"
for (ScoreCheck = 0; ScoreCheck < 10; ScoreCheck++)
{
    score[ScoreCheck] = ScoreCheck; // just put everone somewhere
}

ScoreCheck = 0;
while ( ScoreCheck < 9 ) // check to see if we've reached the last person
{
    // check to see if the person lower on the chart ate more
    if ( anArray[score[ScoreCheck]] < anArray[score[ScoreCheck+1]] )
    {
        // swap person 1 and 2, since 2 ate more that 1
        int tmp = score[ScoreCheck];
        score[ScoreCheck]   = score[ScoreCheck+1];
        score[ScoreCheck+1] = tmp;

        // now go back to the beggining to make
        // sure they are in order from begining to end
        ScoreCheck = 0;
        continue;
    }

    // nope, it's in order so far
    // increment to the next person on the chart
    ScoreCheck++
}
```

Comment: See my post above, the sorting's solved. I'm having trouble printing it out with the names though.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2043902/wolfgang-skyler) by Wolfgang Skyler describes a [sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). You need a minor addition to the algorithm: something that remembers how the elements were swapped. One easy-to-understand solution is an additional array that starts sorted, and gets permuted in exactly the same way as the `score` array:

```
BreakfastNames names[] = {
    NED, // 0
    ARYA, // 1
    JON, // 2
    ROBB, // 3
    SANSA, // 4
    CATELYN, // 5
    BRAN, // 6
    THEON, // 7
    HODOR, // 8
    GHOST // 9
};

// Code by Wolfgang Skyler goes here
    ...
    // swap person 1 and 2, since 2 ate more that 1
    int tmp = score[ScoreCheck];
    score[ScoreCheck]   = score[ScoreCheck+1];
    score[ScoreCheck+1] = tmp;

    BreakfastNames tmp1 = names[ScoreCheck];
    names[ScoreCheck]   = names[ScoreCheck+1];
    names[ScoreCheck+1] = tmp1;
    ...
```

---

It is also possible to adapt [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2373664/jon) even though you don't implement the sorting algorithm. To do it, use the third parameter of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) so it sorts the array `names` but compares the data in `scores`:

```
struct MyComparison
{
    ...
    bool operator()(BreakfastNames name1, BreakfastNames name2)
    {
        ...
        return whatever1 < whatever2;
    }
};

sort(names, names + 10, MyComparison(scores));
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've sorted most of it with the following code:

```
sort(anArray, anArray + 10);

for(int ooo=0; ooo < 10; ooo++)
{
    cout << anArray[ooo] << endl;
}
```

Now the question is how I would solve it to get the names next to the results. I'm feeling like I should go back and make the array multi dimensional, so I'd get a set value for the name as well as the number of pancakes eaten, would this be a good way to go about it or would you recommend something else?