# Simple std::sort not working

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int intArr[] = { 1,5,3 };
    //auto f = [](auto a, auto b) {return a < b;};
    //std::sort(intArr, intArr + 2, f);
    std::sort(intArr, intArr + 2);
    for (int& temp : intArr)
        cout << temp << endl;
}
```

However, the output is unsorted (e.g. the output is `1 5 3`). The same result when using `std::sort` with lambda. What is causing this behavior?

I am using Visual C++ compiler (Visual Studio 2015).

Comment: `std::sort(intArr, intArr + 3);`

Comment: You only sort the first two elements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897319/how-to-use-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-in-c

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I believe this is a decent question.

Comment: That may not be a fancy question, and neither will make it into the hall of fame nor yield great rep gain for answerers, but it **is** a valid and well-formulated question; thus there's no reason to down-vote it.

Comment: Just reading documentation for `std::sort` would answer this question.

Comment: @Satus : It is a very reasonable mistake to assume that you have to include point till the last element, and not its end as well. And many other non-downvoted (even upvoted) questions on the site can be solved with much less effort than that. All I'm saying is that this question showed enough effort, a well curated example, and enough information.

Comment: @therainmaker It is even more reasonable to read documentation of some library function before you post a question about it. And the fact that  "many other non-downvoted (even upvoted) questions on the site can be solved with much less effort than that" is not a justification for not downvoting the questing, but a problem of stackoverflow as a question-answer platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In STL algorithms that take ranges, if you want to provide the whole range you have to give as ending an element one-past-the-end and not the end of the range itself, thus in your case:

```
std::sort(intArr, intArr + 3);
```

Or

```
std::sort(intArr, intArr + sizeof(intArr) / sizeof(int));
```

Or even better:

```
std::sort(std::begin(intArr), std::end(intArr));
```

Comment: Surely `sizeof(intArr)/sizeof(intArr[0])`? Which is exactly why the `std::end` version is better; avoids all sorts of common mistakes!

Comment: @Andrew Never debug while standing up. Thanx corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 values in array, but send only 2 (since in STL algorithms second parameter is `past-end iterator`).
Should be

```
std::sort(intArr, intArr + 3);
```