# How can i sort a string with integers in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting, quicksort

I want to sort some strings of the same size. The size of the string can be very large(10^18). How can I sort all the stings in less possible time? The size of all the inputted string will be equal. How can I sort these strings in less amount of time possible?

```
922003001020293839297830207344987344973074734
766352786207892397340783784078348747606208602
182823068326283756515117829362376823572395775
//the size of all the strings are equal
```

Can anyone please explain a better way of sorting?
Thanks Your any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: are all the numbers the same number of digits? Is so then they will sort fine using a string sort

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897319/how-to-use-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-in-c

Comment: I dont know how to sort a string.. would you please explain elaborately

Comment: There is **tons** of information about this online.  do some reasearch, come up with ssomething, and come back if you have problems

Comment: Surely this is too broad?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort a single `std::string` in order of each digit contained within it? Question isn't entirely clear imo.

Comment: Not a single string.. arrays of string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it's done with std::sort from the header algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main(){

    std::vector<std::string> nums{
        "922003001020293839297830207344987344973074734",
        "766352786207892397340783784078348747606208602",
        "182823068326283756515117829362376823572395775"
    };


    std::cout << "unsorted: " << std::endl;
    for (auto i : nums){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end()); //sort it


    std::cout << "\nsorted: " << std::endl;
    for (auto i : nums){
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
unsorted: 
922003001020293839297830207344987344973074734
766352786207892397340783784078348747606208602
182823068326283756515117829362376823572395775

sorted: 
182823068326283756515117829362376823572395775
766352786207892397340783784078348747606208602
922003001020293839297830207344987344973074734
```

Comment: Can u please do it for std::qsort where i will give an input for total number of string

Comment: why do you want to use std::qsort?
std::sort is so simple

Comment: @JahirulIslamMonir Why do you need to use `qsort`? If you're programming in C++ then use C++ algorithms instead of old C functions.

Comment: Oh, yeah and it's old c style, Like Joachim Pileborg said.

Comment: @StackDanny Then you might as well tag your question as C.  If you are using C++ you should use C++ and not *C with Classes*

Comment: I am marking it as a Accepted answer.. Those who gave negative vote i have nothing to say them.. I just only word to say that i am a beginner in programming and also in Stackoverflow

Comment: @JahirulIslamMonir thank you. Also, if you'd like to avoid negative votes, show us what you have tried so far. And if you have no clue but you really need to do this, try to look for examples sorting strings (there are tons of).
Or at least, ask what's up with std::qsort (like what do I need to pass over).
Just tell a little bit more about your problem. :) good luck on next question!

Answer (score 1):

It just so happens to be that a string containing only digits is *alphabetically* sortable, so you just put each [string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) into a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and simply [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector.

As noted, this only works if the "numbers" all have the same number of digits. Else you need pad the strings with leading zeroes so they are all of the same length. The leading zeroes can then be removed once you have sorted the vector.

Comment: That's only the case if they all have the same number of digits. A normal string sort would put `"10"` before `"2"`.

Comment: Would it be faster to convert the strings into numbers and store them in a vector, sort and convert them back, or pad?

Comment: It would probably be faster just to compare the lengths first, and then do the lexicographical comparison only if they are the same length.

Comment: It will be very costly considering my problem time limit.

Comment: Instead of padding you can use the size first and then the value in a comparison function.

Comment: @JahirulIslamMonir There is no native type for 45-digit numbers.