# How does the range-based for work for plain arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, foreach, c++11

In C++11 you can use a range-based `for`, which acts as the `foreach` of other languages. It works even with plain C arrays:

```
int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
for (int& n : numbers) {
    n *= 2;
}
```

How does it know when to stop? Does it only work with static arrays that have been declared in the same scope the `for` is used in? How would you use this `for` with dynamic arrays?

Comment: There are no "dynamic" arrays in C or C++ per se - there are array types and then there are pointers that may or may not point to an array or a dynamically-allocated block of memory that mostly behaves like an array. For any array of type T[n], its size is encoded in the type and can be accessed by `for`. But the moment that array decays to a pointer, the size information is lost.

Comment: In your example, the number of elements in `numbers` is `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int)`, for instance.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It works for any expression whose type is an array. For example:

```
int (*arraypointer)[4] = new int[1][4]{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
for(int &n : *arraypointer)
  n *= 2;
delete [] arraypointer;
```

For a more detailed explanation, if the type of the expression passed to the right of `:` is an array type, then the loop iterates from `ptr` to `ptr + size` (`ptr` pointing to the first element of the array, `size` being the element count of the array).

This is in contrast to user defined types, which work by looking up `begin` and `end` as members if you pass a class object or (if there is no members called that way) non-member functions. Those functions will yield the begin and end iterators (pointing to directly after the last element and the begin of the sequence respectively).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648878/range-based-for-statement-definition-redundancy) clears up why that difference exists.

Comment: I think the question was _how_ does it work, not _when_ does it work

Comment: @sehe the question contained multiple '?'es. One was "Does it work with ... ?". I explained both of *how* and *when* it works.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub: I think the "how" issue here is how exactly you get the size of an object of an array type in the first place (because of the pointers vs. arrays confusion, not nearly everyone knows that the size of an array *is* available to the programmer.)

Comment: I believe it *only* looks for non-member `begin`\`end`.  It just happens that `std::begin`\`std::end` use the member functions, and will be used if a better match is not available.

Comment: @Dennis no in Madrid it was decided to change that and to favor begin and end members. To not favor begin and end members caused ambiguities that are difficult to avoid.

Comment: Well this topic was just ripe with misinformation then, thanks.

Comment: If using something like `clang` which has C99 Support, does this still work? Or not?

Answer (score 58):

I think that the most important part of this question is, how C++ knows what the size of an array is (at least I wanted to know it when I found this question).

C++ knows the size of an array, because it's a part of the array's definition - it's the type of the variable. A compiler has to know the type.

Since C++11 `std::extent` can be used to obtain the size of an array:

```
int size1{ std::extent< char[5] >::value };
std::cout << "Array size: " << size1 << std::endl;
```

Of course, this doesn't make much sense, because you have to explicitly provide the size in the first line, which you then obtain in the second line. But you can also use `decltype` and then it gets more interesting:

```
char v[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };
int size2{ std::extent< decltype(v) >::value };
std::cout << "Array size: " << size2 << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is indeed what I was originally asking about. :)

Comment: The array size, it is exactly the answer I was looking for. Since when you convert your old array for loops into foreach loops, you wonder how can it work now on a primitive array without any added information about the array size... Thank you so much for your great answer.

Answer (score 21):

According to the latest C++ Working Draft (n3376) the ranged for statement is equivalent to the following:

```
{
    auto && __range = range-init;
    for (auto __begin = begin-expr,
              __end = end-expr;
            __begin != __end;
            ++__begin) {
        for-range-declaration = *__begin;
        statement
    }
}
```

So it knows how to stop the same way a regular `for` loop using iterators does.

I think you may be looking for something like the following to provide a way to use the above syntax with arrays which consist of only a pointer and size (dynamic arrays):

```
template <typename T>
class Range
{
public:
    Range(T* collection, size_t size) :
        mCollection(collection), mSize(size)
    {
    }

    T* begin() { return &mCollection[0]; }
    T* end () { return &mCollection[mSize]; }

private:
    T* mCollection;
    size_t mSize;
};
```

This class template can then be used to create a range, over which you can iterate using the new *ranged for* syntax. I am using this to run through all animation objects in a scene which is imported using a library that only returns a pointer to an array and a size as separate values.

```
for ( auto pAnimation : Range<aiAnimation*>(pScene->mAnimations, pScene->mNumAnimations) )
{
    // Do something with each pAnimation instance here
}
```

This syntax is, in my opinion, much clearer than what you would get using `std::for_each` or a plain `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

It knows when to stop because it knows the bounds of static arrays.

I'm not sure what do you mean by "dynamic arrays", in any case, if not iterating over static arrays, informally, the compiler looks up the names `begin` and `end` in the scope of the class of the object you iterate over, or looks up for `begin(range)` and `end(range)` using argument-dependent lookup and uses them as iterators.

For more information, in the C++11 standard (or public draft thereof), "6.5.4 The range-based `for` statement", pg.145

Comment: A "dynamic array" would be one created with `new[]`. In that case, you've only got a pointer with no indication of the size, so there's no way for the range-based `for` to work with it.

Comment: My answer includes a dynamic array whose size (4) is known at compile time, but I don't know whether that interpretation of "dynamic array" is what the questioner intended.

Answer (score 3):

> How does the range-based for work for plain arrays?

Is that to read as, "*Tell me what a ranged-for does (with arrays)?*"

I'll answer assuming that - Take the following example using nested arrays:

```
int ia[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};

for (auto &pl : ia)
```

Text version:

`ia` is an array of arrays ("nested array"), containing `[3]` arrays, with each containing `[4]` values. The above example loops through `ia` by it's primary 'range' (`[3]`), and therefore loops `[3]` times. Each loop produces one of `ia`'s `[3]` primary values starting from the first and ending with the last - An array containing `[4]` values.

- First loop: `pl` equals `{1,2,3,4}` - An array
- Second loop: `pl` equals `{5,6,7,8}` - An array
- Third loop: `pl` equals `{9,10,11,12}` - An array

Before we explain the process, here are some friendly reminders about arrays:

- Arrays are interpreted as pointers to their first value - Using an array without any iteration returns the address of the first value
- `pl` *must* be a reference because we cannot copy arrays
- With arrays, when you add a number to the array object itself, it advances forward that many times and 'points' to the equivalent entry - If `n` is the number in question, then `ia[n]` is the same as `*(ia+n)` (We're dereferencing the address that's `n` entries forward), and `ia+n` is the same as `&ia[n]` (We're getting the address of the that entry in the array).

**Here's what's going on:**

- On each loop, `pl` is set as a *reference* to `ia[n]`, with `n` equaling the current loop count starting from 0. So, `pl` is `ia[0]` on the first round, on the second it's `ia[1]`, and so on. It retrieves the value via iteration.
- The loop goes on so long as `ia+n` is less than `end(ia)`.

...And that's about it.

It's really just a **simplified way to write this**:

```
int ia[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
for (int n = 0; n != 3; ++n)
  auto &pl = ia[n];
```

---

If your array *isn't* nested, then this process becomes a bit simpler in that a reference is *not* needed, because the iterated value isn't an array but rather a 'normal' value:

```
 int ib[3] = {1,2,3};

 // short
 for (auto pl : ib)
   cout << pl;

 // long
 for (int n = 0; n != 3; ++n)
   cout << ib[n];
```

---

**Some additional information**

What if we didn't want to use the `auto` keyword when creating `pl`? What would that look like?

In the following example, `pl` refers to an `array of four integers`. On each loop `pl` is given the value `ia[n]`:

```
int ia[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
for (int (&pl)[4] : ia)
```

---

And... That's how it works, with additional information to brush away any confusion. It's just a 'shorthand' `for` loop that automatically counts for you, but lacks a way to retrieve the current loop without doing it manually.

Comment: @Andy 9 out of 10 times the *title* is what matches in Google/whatever searches - The title asks *how do these work?*, not *when does it know when to stop?*. Even so, the underlying question implied *is* covered in this answer to some extent, and goes on to answer for anyone else looking for the *other* answer. Syntax questions such as these should have titles phrased so that an answer can be written using that alone because that's all the information the searcher needs to find the question. You're certainly not wrong - The question isn't titled as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Some sample code to demonstrate the difference between arrays on Stack vs arrays on Heap

```
/**
 * Question: Can we use range based for built-in arrays
 * Answer: Maybe
 * 1) Yes, when array is on the Stack
 * 2) No, when array is the Heap
 * 3) Yes, When the array is on the Stack,
 *    but the array elements are on the HEAP
 */
void testStackHeapArrays() {
  int Size = 5;
  Square StackSquares[Size];  // 5 Square's on Stack
  int StackInts[Size];        // 5 int's on Stack
  // auto is Square, passed as constant reference
  for (const auto &Sq : StackSquares)
    cout << "StackSquare has length " << Sq.getLength() << endl;
  // auto is int, passed as constant reference
  // the int values are whatever is in memory!!!
  for (const auto &I : StackInts)
    cout << "StackInts value is " << I << endl;

  // Better version would be: auto HeapSquares = new Square[Size];
  Square *HeapSquares = new Square[Size];   // 5 Square's on Heap
  int *HeapInts = new int[Size];            // 5 int's on Heap

  // does not compile,
  // *HeapSquares is a pointer to the start of a memory location,
  // compiler cannot know how many Square's it has
  // for (auto &Sq : HeapSquares)
  //    cout << "HeapSquare has length " << Sq.getLength() << endl;

  // does not compile, same reason as above
  // for (const auto &I : HeapInts)
  //  cout << "HeapInts value is " << I << endl;

  // Create 3 Square objects on the Heap
  // Create an array of size-3 on the Stack with Square pointers
  // size of array is known to compiler
  Square *HeapSquares2[]{new Square(23), new Square(57), new Square(99)};
  // auto is Square*, passed as constant reference
  for (const auto &Sq : HeapSquares2)
    cout << "HeapSquare2 has length " << Sq->getLength() << endl;

  // Create 3 int objects on the Heap
  // Create an array of size-3 on the Stack with int pointers
  // size of array is known to compiler
  int *HeapInts2[]{new int(23), new int(57), new int(99)};
  // auto is int*, passed as constant reference
  for (const auto &I : HeapInts2)
    cout << "HeapInts2 has value " << *I << endl;

  delete[] HeapSquares;
  delete[] HeapInts;
  for (const auto &Sq : HeapSquares2) delete Sq;
  for (const auto &I : HeapInts2) delete I;
  // cannot delete HeapSquares2 or HeapInts2 since those arrays are on Stack
}
```