# Using OpenMP with C++11 range-based for loops?

Tags: c++11, openmp

Is there any counter-indication to doing this ? Or is the behavior well specified?

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(auto x : stl_container)
{
   ...
}
```

Because it seems that OpenMP specification is only valid for c++98 but I guess there might be more incompatibilities due to C++11 threads, which are not used here. I wanted to be sure, still.

Comment: + Good question. Want to know that, too.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

OpenMP 5.0 adds the following line on page 99, which makes a lot of range-based for loops OK !

> 2.12.1.3 A range-based for loop with random access iterator has a canonical loop form.

Source : https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5.0.pdf

Comment: OpenMP 5.0 also provides initial support for C++14 and C++17.  Not all of the features in those base language are supported, however.

Comment: Ok, but, which compiler does support OpenMP 5.0?

Comment: At least GCC 9+, Clang 10+ should support this feature.

Answer (score 56):

The OpenMP 4.0 specification was finalised and published several days ago [here](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/). It still mandates that parallel loops should be in the canonical form (§2.6, p.51):

> `for (`*init-expr*`;` *test-expr*`;` *incr-expr*`)` *structured-block*

The standard allows for containers that provide random-access iterators to be used in all of the expressions, e.g.:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)
{
   ...
}
```

If you still insist on using the C++11 syntactic sugar, and if it takes a (comparatively) lot of time to process each element of `stl_container`, then you could use the single-producer tasking pattern:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single
   {
      for (auto x : stl_container)
      {
         #pragma omp task
         {
            // Do something with x, e.g.
            compute(x);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Tasking induces certain overhead so it would make no sense to use this pattern if `compute(x);` takes very little time to complete.

Comment: I think that iterators are the way to go by now, but if you want your code to compile with gcc you need to substitute != with < otherwise you get an "invalid controlling predicate" error. By the way, do you know why?

Comment: According to this website : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/RandomAccessIterator/ 
it should work...

Comment: In that website they don't put any pragma before the cycle. Just try to compile it :)

Comment: @DarioP, the `!=` is an Intel-ism - the standard does not allow it to be used, but `icpc` is smart enough to deduce what's going on in the loop. I had it corrected. That's also one of the reasons why random-access iterators are required - the usual iterators only provide the `==` and `!=` operators.

Comment: It seems that at least with apple clang 12.0.0, `std::map` has no random access iter, so the `<` relation doesnt work.

Comment: @HristoIliev, what is the type of ``it`` in your first code-snippet? Surely it does not compile the way it is now. It is of the same type as the elements of ``v`` ? Thanks

Comment: @velenos14 it is of the type returned by `v.begin()`. In modern C++ that could be `auto`.