# C++ openmp - paralellizing loop with iterator pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, parallel-processing, iterator, openmp

I want to use OpenMP with iterator pattern.
But it says syntax error. Is there some way to get this run with iterator pattern? Don't want to work with indexes.

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for 
for (Food * thisFood : food){
...
}
}
```

Comment: Not really but somehow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848521/using-openmp-with-c11-range-based-for-loops

Comment: @Pixelchemist the post you mention use the task construct, and I agree that it do it! but for the `for` construct even OpenMP v4 is limited to the old C++98 feature, so the new C++11 for (iterator pattern) will not be distribute among multiple thread [read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837696/can-i-safely-use-openmp-with-c11)

Comment: @alexbuisson That's what I mean by "not really".