# A minimal code way to parallelize a for loop in C++

Tags: c++

In 2019, is there a platform-agnostic (Intel, AMD, Windows, *nix, etc.) way to simply parallelize a for loop, with minimal additional code to use all cores available. Here, it is assume the code within the for loop is written in a thread-safe manner. Let us also assume the latest and greatest language versions are supported.

Let's say this simple code is what I have:

```
std::vector<SomeObject> objects;
for (const auto& object: objects) {
// do some thread-safe work with object
// how to parallelize this?
}
```

Comment: While the duplicate is correct, most of the answers are terribly outdated. See [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) which accepts an execution policy allowing parallelization.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If there's a newer, better answer to that question, there's no reason not to add it there.

Comment: Hmmm, why didn't the question police bot not suggest that question to me when asking this question? That bot needs to be improved.

Comment: What about [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with execution policy of [std::execution::parallel_policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) ?

Comment: @Caleb that was asked when C++17 didn't exist. This question seems like a duplicate, but is an unsolved problem. Specially with multi core PCs becoming prevalent.

Comment: @dev_nut There's [at least one C++17 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45773308/643383) there, and it seems in line with François Andrieux's comment. Won't that work for your problem?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux No worries, I missed whatever you wrote. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) is what you are looking for.

And if you need to compute in multiple nodes, try [MPI](http://mpitutorial.com/tutorials/mpi-hello-world/).