# do efficiently floor function on all item's in std::vector

Tags: c++, performance, std, floor, ceil

i want to floor all the items in a std::vector and use bellow code :

```
for(const float &number : numbers)
     number = floor(number);
```

but I need to use a parallel algorithm for this operation.is there any parallel algorithm in standard c++ for do efficiently an action like floor function on all items?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallel Loops in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246300/parallel-loops-in-c)

Comment: consider also vectorize your code which usually result in more speed improvement unless your CPU has too many cores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use C++17, you can use the `ExecutionPolicy` argument from `std::for_each` to parallelize your loop

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <execution>

std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,
              numbers.begin(),
              numbers.end(),
              [](double& number){ number = std::floor(number); });
```