# How do we get a progress bar for parallel for loops in C++ using TDQM inspired libraries?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, progress-bar, tqdm

I currently use https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm.cpp as the progress bar in my software.
Which I code something like this.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include "tqdm.hpp"

int main()
{
    for (int a : tq::trange(10))
    {
        // a will be in {0,1,...,9}
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

How do I display a similar progress bar which takes input from all running processes and shows updates in a single progress bar in programs like below? [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246300/parallel-loops-in-c)

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> foo;
std::for_each(
    std::execution::par_unseq,
    foo.begin(),
    foo.end(),
    [](auto&& item)
    {
        //do stuff with item
    });
```