# why can't int type be the iterator in STL vector?

Tags: stl

The question is first question on the book 《c++ STL》 after the chapter `vector`. I can't answer it.And I can't find the answer while surfing the Internet.

Comment: is it really an STL vector, or rather `std::vector` from the C++ standard library? anyway, an iterator must be dereferenceable. you can't dereference an `int`.

Comment: Sorry but I can't find a book named "C++ STL". Is it N.M. Josuttis' "The C++ Standard Library"? I looked up this one at [Safari](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/) but I cannot find the question you are speaking of.

Comment: P.J. Plauger wrote it. 《C++ Standard Template Library》 .Maybe the name is different in different country.@TobiMcNamobi

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it's asking.  If it means what you say:  why _can't_ ints be iterators -- it's because ints aren't iterators.  Iterators are specific classes that have operations that don't make sense for ints (dereferencing), and ints have operations that don't make sense for iterators (division).

But if the question means why shouldn't you use int instead of iterator in a for-loop -- see this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702561/c-iterate-through-vector-using-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious answer to the question (as asked) is that an iterator needs to act like a pointer, so for some arbitrary iterator, `*iterator` is valid code (with `*` acting as a unary operator).

For an `int`, that would not be the case--given some `i` of type `int`, you can't use `*i` (except in a context where the `*` will be interpreted as a binary operator, such as `j *i` doing multiplication).