# Is there an equivalent of php "foreach" in c++ array

Tags: c++, foreach

As in title, is there any kind of "foreach" equivalent for arrays, or its just for vectors?
I've already asked a computer science professor and he answered it only for more complex structures, none of the ones we'll see in the course.

Comment: @timrau: Ermmmm not really?!

Comment: The question I proposed as duplicate itself is indeed the answer to this question.

Comment: @timrau: Not really, no.

Comment: Yeah, it's more or less the same; mine is more generic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use algorithms like `for_each`, or range-based for loops, with arrays, as well as any other container:

```
int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

for_each(begin(a), end(a), [](int x){cout << x;});
for (int x : a) cout << x;
```

Answer (score 3):

In c++11 and c++14 there is

```
string[] strarr = {"one","two","three"}; 
for(string str: strarr) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

But otherwise no. You will either have to use an `iterator` or a plain `for-loop`

Answer (score 1):

Your professor is wrong.

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
for (int& x : array)
   x *= 2;

// Array now looks like:
//  {0, 2, 4, 6}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6207d742208d531))

Comment: I wouldn't call him wrong, just outdated. The school was always few years/decades after the edge.

Comment: @qub1n: That makes him wrong at time of writing. He might have been right had he made that claim five years ago (modulo `BOOST_FOREACH`, anyway), but that is not the operative scenario here. I might as well tell you that C++ hasn't been invented yet; you're going to say I'm not wrong?

Comment: No, because If it hasn't been invented, you couldn't have known that it is called C++  and thus you are wrong :-) Don't take it too much logically, it is kind of respect to professor to call him rather outdated then wrong.

Comment: @qub1n: I'd have more respect for him if he actually knew his craft rather than spreading misinformation to defenceless students.

Answer (score 0):

The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963894/c11-how-to-use-range-based-for-loop-with-stdmap) use vector example or [C array example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939399/how-does-the-range-based-for-work-for-plain-arrays). To precisely answer the question, I can told use yes, in C++11 it is possible, but you should better use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

//use [std::array notation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), it is just wrapper over what you know as C Array

```
std::array<int, 3> a3 = {1, 2, 3};
```

And iterate it like this:

```
for(const auto& s: a3)
   std::cout << s << ' ';
```

There exists something like [Microsoft C++ foreach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177203.aspx), but you can consider deprecated, because of C++11 features in this example.