# Can you cast a pointer, into an array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a pointer "a", it is of type A*. I now that there is n objects of type A at that address and I want to iterate over them.

I would like to cast it to A[n], so that I can use the c++11 range-for and write `for (auto temp : a){...}`.
Of course, I can use a classic `for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {temp=a[i]; ...}` but the range-for is cleaner.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use `std::array` instead.

Comment: The size is unkown at compile-time, I used n as example.

Comment: Use an `std::vector` then.

Comment: @user2370139 C++ does not allow you to cast a raw pointer to an array type . So no. You need to implement this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12444983/126769

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting pointer to Array (int\* to int\[2\])](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046429/casting-pointer-to-array-int-to-int2)

Comment: You could use a [`gsl::span`](http://codexpert.ro/blog/2016/03/07/guidelines-support-library-review-spant/)

Comment: or `for (auto&& e : ranges::view::counted(a, n))` with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Answer (score 1):

In *reasonable* code, I'd shy away from it. But C++ allows you to commit acts of sheer devilry. In that vein, I offer a solution:

At the expense of some considerable obfuscation, you can write some preparatory templates:

```
namespace std
{
    template <typename T> T* begin(std::pair<T*, T*> const& a)
    {
        return a.first;
    }

    template <typename T> T* end(std::pair<T*, T*> const& a)
    {
        return a.second;
    }
}
```

Then you can write something like

```
for (auto&& i : std::make_pair(a, a + n)){

}
```

The template stuff brings in suitable definitions of `begin` and `end` which is required by the range `for` loop.

Comment: Isn't it UB to add these overloads into the `std` namespace?

Comment: Not, I think, for template specialisations; even partial ones. Cf `std::hash`. Perhaps an expert can confirm.

Comment: I think that who worked on standard should think about using result of `std::equal_range` in for range loop.

Comment: @NathanOliver: `[C++14: 17.6.4.2.1/1]` looks ok _iff_ `T` is user-defined.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: But we cannot add this restriction on `T` (via `std::enable_if`for example :-/)

Comment: @Jarod42: You can't get the compiler to enforce it for you, no.

Comment: `for (auto&& e : ranges::view::counted(a, n))` with [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).