# c++ perform sequence-for to plain array

Tags: c++

The c++ sequence-for based on `sequence.begin()/end()/++`,but the plain array such as `int a[10];` can also perform this.Why?Is there some implicit cast from plain array to `std::array`?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7939399/3002139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain arrays [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) uses special handling:

> If `range_expression` is an expression of array type, then `begin_expr` is `__range` and `end_expr` is `(__range + __bound)`, where `__bound` is the number of elements in the array (if the array has unknown size or is of an incomplete type, the program is ill-formed)