# Exactly how range for works?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, reference

I was reading about "range `for`" statements when I got confused how it exactly works.

Below is a program to convert a string to Uppercase.

```
string s("Hello World!!!");

//convert s to uppercase

for( auto &c :s )  // for every char in s
   c= topper(c);   //  c is a reference,so the assignment changes the 
                   //  char in s
cout<< s << endl;
```

How is the reference to the string (that is, `c`) is changing elements to upppercase?

I've searched about how iteration could work here, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: `c` is a `char&` not a `std::string&`.

Comment: [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) you can find a detailed explanation

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - To the answer section please if you intend to correct the OP.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939399/how-does-the-range-based-for-work-for-plain-arrays

Comment: The explanation is in the code. If you don't follow it, please tell us which part you don't follow. Otherwise we are simply doomed to repeat the explanation...

Answer (score 6):

This piece of code

```
for (auto& c : s)
{
    c = toupper(c); 
}
```

roughly translates to this

```
for (auto it = std::begin(s); it != std::end(s); ++it)
{
    auto& c = *it;
    c = toupper(c);
}
```

which is a basic iterator loop, covered in any beginner C++ book.

---

cppreference has a [more detailed and precise explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 2):

"c" is not an ordinary variable, it acts as a proxy (or reference) to each element (character) in the string.

By changing "c" you are in fact changing the value which "c" is refering to.

Comment: @user463035818 It's not unfair to call references "not ordinary variables" at this level

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well on second read I got it. Sometimes I am faster in writing than thinking ;)