# working of range for loop and C-style arrays in C++

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, c++14, c++17

C-style Arrays are not self-describing as it doesn't has any information about it's size, so for iterating it's elements we need size information somehow. I'm confused as how range-for loop gets the size information. It is expected to fail. Consider 2 conflicting examples,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    for(auto x : a)
        cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It ran successfully(unexpected), but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_a(int*);

void print_a(int a[])
{
    for(auto x : a)
        cout<<x<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}
int main() { 
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    print_a(a);
    return 0;
}
```

This produced errors(expected).

Can someone explain as how range-for loop actually works ?

Comment: "C-style Arrays are not self-describing as it doesn't has any information about it's size" That's not right. It does contain this information (implicitly - it's not stored anywhere, but compiler knows it), but arrays decay to a pointer when passed to a function.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen but then how actually is range for getting this info about size

Comment: In the first example, the compiler has visibility that `a` is an array and of the size of that array, so can work out the range the `for` loop can iterate over.    I assume you don't need an explanation of why the second example doesn't work.

Comment: "Arrays are not self-describing because the number of elements of an array is not guaranteed to
be stored with the array. This implies that to traverse an array that does not contain a terminator the
way C-style strings do, we must somehow supply the number of elements" quoting from 'TC++PL'

Comment: [How does the range-based for work for plain arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939399/how-does-the-range-based-for-work-for-plain-arrays) and [cppreference for range-based loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). In short, C-style arrays are handled separately when used in range-based for loops. Note that it only works with actual array type, not arrays that decayed to pointers.

Comment: The compiler can, however, examine the definition of an array to obtain its size.   It can't do that if only given a pointer (which can point to a single value, or to the first of any number of values).

Comment: `a` in main is of type `int[6]`, ie the size is part of its type. `a` in `print_a` is a `int*` which has lost all information on the array size

Comment: @idclev463035818 even if we had int[] in declaration of print_a, it will eventually decay to int*

Comment: `void print_a(int*);` and `void print_a(int a[]);` are two declarations of the same function

Answer (score -1):

range-for loop run from start to end that says it needs to know the length.
of statically allocated arrays AKA `int array[10]` the compiler know the length on compile-time  so he knows to terminate them,
but on the dynamically allocated array, the compiler doesn't know the length of the array so he cants rang loop them

Comment: That's not entirely true, since statically allocated arrays can decay to pointers and thus lose information about their length. The code in this question is a prime example for this.