# How to Write the Range-based For-Loop With Argv?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11

From the c++0x Wikipedia site:

```
int my_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int &x : my_array) {
    x *= 2;
}
```

So why does this code not work?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (char *arg : argv)
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(char**&)’
```

I am using Qt with g++ 4.6.1 on Ubuntu 11.10.

**Additional Information**

[Is There a Range Class in C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185437/is-there-a-range-class-in-c0x-aka-c11-for-use-with-range-based-for-loops)

[Range-Based For-Loop Statement Definition Redundance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648878/range-based-for-statement-definition-redundancy)

Comment: Note that (depending, of course, on the nature of the possible arguments and the type of processing you're trying to do on them) using a range-based for loop in this specific situation may be quite limiting - because you're forced to process one argument per loop iteration.  Using an explicit iterator (or pointer) lets you advance immediately from one argument to the next - often the desired action when processing arguments like "-f myfile.out".  With a range-based for loop you're likely to end up needing explicit state variables or similar.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't, because the system can't tell how long `argv` is at compile time. Someone can likely find the proper section of the standard to quote you about this.

There is a way around it though, and that's to create a custom class to wrap `argv`. It's not even that hard.

```
class argv_range {
 public:
   argv_range(int argc, const char * const argv[])
        : argc_(argc), argv_(argv)
   {
   }

   const char * const *begin() const { return argv_; }
   const char * const *end() const { return argv_ + argc_; }

 private:
   const int argc_;
   const char * const *argv_;
};
```

Here's how you use it:

```
for (const char *arg: argv_range(argc, argv)) {
   // Do something.
}
```

Yeah, I use a lot of `const`s. Basically, `argv` is an array of character pointers, none of which should be modified, each pointing to a string, none of the characters of which should be modified either.

Comment: You're right, it isn't hard, but I didn't think of the problem like you did :D I thought the level of indirection with my 'char *arg' was wrong. Yeah, way off. Thanks for the tip and the code!

Comment: @SoulBeaver: _nod_ The -1 poster I think thought the same thing. But that error message is because the ranged-for construct is trying to figure out how to shoehorn your bare char ** into some sort of thing it knows how to deal with. The last resort is to try to call `being(thing)` and `end(thing)` to get something iterator-like to use.

Comment: @SoulBeaver: Here's a nice SO answer that details the requirements on ranges you use for range-based for loops: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648878/range-based-for-statement-definition-redundancy - I believe the default definitions of the `begin` and `end` free functions try to call `x.begin()` and `x.end()` where `x` is their argument (a reference to the range).

Comment: I included that plus another similar and hopefully useful question as a footer to my question so that other people can easily find and access the same knowledge :)

Comment: If Boost is available, you can instead do `auto argv_range = [](size_t len, char const *const ptr) { return boost::make_iterator_range(ptr, ptr+len); }` or an equivalent function. I use a lambda just to avoid spelling out the return type, which is `boost::iterator_range<char const *const>`.

Comment: This would make a nice template tool for any array where you know the length and the pointer to some type.  template<typename T> ptr_range {...  There's still a lot of APIs out there that return pointers from new [] or malloc even.  They should bless boost::make_iterator_range(ptr, ptr+len) maybe.

Comment: Sadly this won't work to me on Visual Studio 2010, this is from C++11

Comment: @JohnBoe - Well, range based for loops are from C++11 too, so even the original question isn't relevant to you.

Answer (score 32):

Usually, the first thing I do with `argc` and `argv` is this:

```
std::vector<std::string> arguments(argv, argv + argc);
```

Now I have a vector of strings to work with and I can easily use not only the range-based for loops, but also C++ standard library facilities.

```
for(std::string& s : arguments) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

The wikipedia code works because the type of `my_array` is a variable of array type.
The original code does not work, because `argv` is not an array. The syntax `char* argv[]` may make it look like it is an array, but that's just a sad artifact of C syntax. `char* argv[]` is *exactly* the same as `char** argv`. `argv` is not an array; it's actually just a pointer.

The range-based for loop works on:

- arrays;
- any type that has member functions `begin()` and `end()` that return iterators;
- any type for which exist non-member functions `begin` and `end` that can be called like `begin(x)` and `end(x)`, with `x` being the thing that you're iterating over.

As you can see, pointers are not part of this list.

Comment: +1: That works too. Though it's not as efficient, it has its distinct advantages.

Comment: @Fernandes: This is my usual procedure as well, but for this program I already know what type of input to expect, so I tried to avoid parsing it into a vector and then a second vector of the expected type. I just wanted to process each incoming argument and then convert it to the right type before insertion into my vector.

Comment: @SoulBeaver well, then your only option is to create a range type, like Omnifarious showed :)

Comment: Copying into `string`s also helps to get rid of the limited [modifiability](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function#Explanation) of the original `argv` elements.

Answer (score 9):

You can use C++20 [`std::span()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) or [`gsl::span()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) to make view for `argv`:

```cpp
for (auto const arg : std::span(argv, argc)) {
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}
```

Or similar, using [Ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) ([`std::view::counted()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_counted)):

```cpp
for (auto const arg : std::views::counted(argv, argc)) {
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}
```

or directly using [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange):

```cpp
for (auto const arg : std::ranges::subrange{argv, argv+argc}) {
    std::cout << arg << '\n';
}
```

Comment: To clarify that all the constructs are forC++20  :-(

Comment: What is the exact type of the subrange in this case? It is not: `using Args = std::ranges::subrange<const char**>;` nor `using Args = std::ranges::subrange<const char*>;`

Comment: With Clang++-13 the subrange thing does not seem to work.

Comment: @BitTickler, https://godbolt.org/z/6EWGj46xe sounds like it is Clang++ bug. Clang 16 work well: https://godbolt.org/z/Yb7sMT5hr

Answer (score 6):

The vector solution proposed copies the array (the pointers only, not the strings<sup>1</sup> - but still). Unnessary. The argv_range solution is what I would have tried, too, if I absolutely wanted to enforce a range based loop. But that produces a lot of extra code (admitted, only once, if you write it to a header file and keep it, but still).

The classic loop appears so easy to me that I allow myself just to post it, I don't consider it worth to have all this effort just to have a range based loop...

```cpp
for (char** a = argv; *a; ++a)
{
    // use *a, or if you don't like:
    char* arg = *a;
    // use arg...
}
```

Or, if you won't ever need the argv array afterwards any more:

```cpp
for (++argv; *argv; ++argv)
{
    // use *argv, or if you don't like:
    char* a = *argv;
    // use a...
}
```

There is a little difference, you might have noticed: In the first variant, I iterate over all the values, in the second, I leave out the first one (which normally is the program name we are not interested in in many cases). The other way round, for each:

```cpp
for (char** a = argv + 1; *a; ++a);
for (; *argv; ++argv);
```

Note that all these variants profit from the fact that the strings array itself is null-pointer-terminated as well, just as any of the strings is null-character-terminated, thus the simple checks for `*a` or `*argv`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>This applies only, if using `std::vector<char*>`; if using `std::vector<std::string>`, as actually proposed, even the strings themselves are copied!</sub>

Comment: OK -- before anyone grumps -- I know I'm late. Just wanted to add an alternative for the late readers like me...

Comment: Simple but perfect!

Answer (score -1):

argv is a double pointer, argv**

So where &x creates a reference to the element in the array, your *arg does not create a reference but rather is the same type as every element in argv.

Comment: -1: This is confusing, not relevant to the problem the OP is having, and possibly wrong.

Comment: How is it not relevant? His syntax is wrong which is why he is having compile errors. Pointers and referencing were confused. Christ, people get a few K points and feel the need to rate down for no reason on SO nowadays.

Comment: Except, his syntax isn't wrong. The thing that's wrong is that `argv` is not a valid range.

Comment: So you're telling me if I had used a different, self defined double pointer array besides argv, that code would have worked? If not, then correct me if im wrong, but that is the definition of a syntax error.

Comment: Well, not a double pointer array exactly. If you had a declaration like `char *argv[30];` it would worked perfectly. That because the compiler can detect a bound on `argv`. If you had `char *stuff[30]; char **argv = stuff;` it would've failed again with the same error. The problem has nothing to do with whether or not references are being used or anything like that. It's all about whether the thing given as the range can be construed as a valid range by the compiler.

Comment: The syntax is fine. It's a semantic error. It can even be made to "work" even with `argv`. Just add `int* begin(char**) { return nullptr; } int* end(char**) { return nullptr; }` and it compiles. The syntax is fine.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Err, `char **begin(char **) { return nullptr; }` is what I think you meant. :-)

Comment: In support of the point @Omnifarious made, `char** argv[]` is not necessary actually. `char* argv[]` works fine too!

Answer (score -1):

I take you'd like the range based loop in order to not have to write that much..

so to annoy c++ purists, while at the same time not exactly answering your question, we'd like to post some nicely unsafe ways to do it without any `std::vector` or OO-wrapper-crap :)

```
for (;argc--; argv++) {
    printf(" %s \n ", *argv);
}
```

or

```
while (argc--) {
    printf(" %s \n ", *(argv++));
}
```

or even

```
while (*argv) {
    printf(" %s \n ", *(argv++));
}
```