# How to perform a range-based c++11 for loop on char* argv[]?

Tags: c++11, for-loop, range

I would like to try out c++11 range-based for loop on `char* argv[]` but I am getting errors. By current approach is :

```
for( char* c : argv )
{                                                                                               
   printf("param: %s \n", c);                                                                    
}
```

and in my makefile I have the following line :

```
g++ -c -g -std=c++11 -O2 file.cc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Write the Range-based For-Loop With Argv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572991/how-to-write-the-range-based-for-loop-with-argv)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`argv` is an array of pointers to raw strings, you can't obtain a range from it directly.

---

With **C++17** you can use `std::string_view` to avoid allocating strings:

```
for (auto && str : std::vector<std::string_view> { argv, argv + argc })
{
    std::printf("%s\n", str.data()); // Be careful!
    std::cout << str << std::endl;   // Always fine
    fmt::print("{}\n", str);         // <3
}
```

**Take caution** when using `string_view` with `printf` [because](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/data#Notes):

> Unlike `std::basic_string::data()` and string literals, `data()` may return a pointer to a buffer that is not null-terminated.

`argv` always contains null-terminated strings so you're fine here though.

---

Without C++17 you can simply use `std::string`:

```
for (auto && str : std::vector<std::string> { argv, argv + argc })
    std::printf("param: %s\n", str.c_str());
```

---

Starting from C++20 you can use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```
for (auto && str : std::span(argv, argc))
    std::printf("param: %s\n", str);
```

Comment: This works, but: isn't that an overhead to create the vector? and secondly why can't I use `printf("param: %s\n", str);` (I am getting : `cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'const class std::basic_string<char>' through '...')` ?

Comment: To get a `const char *` from a `std::string`, use the [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function : `printf("param: %s\n", str.c_str());`.

Comment: It works but :) in my vim that is linting each c file I get the following on this line :`request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’`. Also in line with `for` I get : `ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘str’ with no type [-fpermissive]`

Comment: The above code compiles and runs fine with your invocation `g++ -c -g -std=c++11 -O2 test.cpp` so you're running into some unrelated problems here.

Comment: I have change auto to `std:string` and I got rid of them:)

Comment: Which g++ version are you running ?

Comment: I use 4.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit)

Comment: Strange, it should had resolve `auto` correctly ... Anyway, if my answer helped you solve your problem, you're invited to accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the range-based loop since you don't have a range.

You can either write your own range wrapper (a kind of "array view"), or just use a normal loop:

```
for (char ** p = argv, e = argv + argc; p != e; ++p)
{
    // use *p
}
```

With a wrapper:

```
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T>
struct array_view
{
    T * first, * last;
    array_view(T * a, std::size_t n) : first(a), last(a + n) {}
    T * begin() const { return first; }
    T * end() const { return last; }
};

template <typename T>
array_view<T> view_array(T * a, std::size_t n)
{
    return array_view<T>(a, n);
}
```

Usage:

```
for (auto s : view_array(argv, argc))
{
    std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```