# C++ Error: no matching function for call to 'reverse(char*&)'

Tags: c++, radix

I'm trying to make code for converting a base4 number into a base2 number.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bits.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

 void itoa(int n, char s[])
 {
     int i, sign;

     if ((sign = n) < 0)
         n = -n;
     i = 0;
     do {
         s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';
     } while ((n /= 10) > 0);
     if (sign < 0)
         s[i++] = '-';
     s[i] = '\0';
     reverse(s);
 }
```

At the end, there is a reverse function. When I run the code, the error in the title appears. I don't know what to do about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what reverse function do you mean?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse

Comment: please include that in the question

Comment: I assume you are trying to use `std::reverse` from the `<algorithm>` standard library module. Please [read the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to see how to call it.

Comment: Or are you trying to use the new [`ranges::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/reverse)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a standard C++ iterator for C strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770586/is-there-a-standard-c-iterator-for-c-strings)

Comment: Nitpick: It's not when you run the code but when you compile the code that the error happens.