# C++ - how to find all subranges which are sandwiched between two values using the STL

Tags: c++, stl

I have an array with integer values in domain [0,258)
I want to find all sub ranges in domain [0,256) which are sandwiched between 256 and 257.
I.e. all sub-ranges of the form {256,...,257} where ... is in domain [0,256).

I've tried a hand-written loop but is there a way to do this with STL?

Comment: Very specific use case, have some doubts about having it available completely out of box. But at least you might use `std::find` to find the borders of your sub-ranges easily – or possibly better `std::find_first_of` (or `std::find_if`) checking for both values such that you might detect e.g. 256 occurring twice before next 257 and apply appropriate error handling – though if there are multiple ranges to find I'm again a bit in doubt these would make the then still necessary loop really more elegant…

Comment: @Aconcagua thank you for your response. My first approach was to find all occurrences of 256, all occurrences of 257, along with their positions, order them by position, then find consecutive pairs of 256 and 257. This should give me a list of iterator pairs corresponding to delimiters. I wonder if [cppitertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools) can do this.

Comment: If the character values are stored in a type that is supported by [C++'s regular expressions library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) (I'm aware of classic `char` and `wchar_t` as well as modern `charN_t` types; not idea if yet other types would work, too, or not) then that might be worth a try.

Comment: The cppitertools are non-standard, though, so not really matching your question ;) Not familiar with, though, you'll need to evaluate yourself.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes you are right. I would rather vanilla STL and not have to pull in a dependency like cppitertools.

Comment: Your initial approach appears too complex to me anyway, you should well be able to run over those sequences in a linear way, e.g. like [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9E31j5Ynh). If you don't need such error handling you might even be fine with a simple boolean and directly process (here: print) all those values while the range is open. Sometimes ordinary loops are just so simple that you get more complexity trying to avoid them, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36012497/1312382) ;).

Comment: The question doesn't seem well defined to me. Should `1,256,2,257,3,256,4,257` return `[256,2,257,3,256,4,257]` in addition to '[256,2,257]` and `[256,4,257]`? If not, successive calls to `std::find` should do the trick. If so, you'd still use `std::find`, but encapsulated in a slightly more complicated algorithm.

Comment: I have something working here https://godbolt.org/z/v58sff5ff

Comment: I have a manual loop version as well. That seems to generate less assembly. https://godbolt.org/z/ad6dKnW16

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/n5WeoKz3j) with `std::find`.

Comment: What output do you expect if after an opening `256` there is a second `256` before `257`? Or when some of these special values is unpaired? E.g. what should be the answer for `256,1,256,2,257`, `3,257,256` and `256,1,256,2,257,3,257`? Or such inputs should be considered impossible or filtered out by calling code?