# Will elements added into a std::unordered_set (or unordered_map) during iteration be visited during the iterations?

Tags: c++, for-loop, unordered-set

I have code that looks like the below:

```
std::unordered_set<int> ht{1,2,3};
ht.reserve(10000);  // ht will not exceed this size

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{ 
  auto j = i;
  for(auto it = ht.begin(); it != ht.end(); ++it)
  {
    // do some stuff
    int v = j++;
    ht.emplace(v);
  }
}
```

For the inner loop, I want to loop from the beginning of ht to the end, but I don't want the loop to go over any of the newly added elements within the loop. In other words, is the above equivalent to the below?

```
std::unordered_set<int> ht{1,2,3};
ht.reserve(10000);  // ht will not exceed this size

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  auto temp = ht;
  auto j = i;
  for(auto it = ht.begin(); it != ht.end(); ++it)
  {
    // do some stuff
    auto v = j++;
    temp.emplace(j);
  }

  ht = temp;
}
```

Based on a few runs that I did, it seems to be equivalent, but I don't know if this is undefined behavior, or if they are indeed equivalent. If the `unordered_set` was changed to a `vector`, this would not work, but it seems the forward iterators work.

Does the answer change if the `ht.reserve(10000);  // ht will not exceed this size` was not present or if `ht` did in fact exceed the reserved capacity, and therefore all the forward iterators will be invalidated?

Comment: [std::unordered_set::reserve](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/reserve) does not do the same thing as `std::vector::reserve`.  It is far more than just allocating space.  Also -- *Based on a few runs that I did,* -- C++ does not work this way, where you can verify (or not verify) that something is safe by a few runs.  It's either undefined behavior, defined behavior, or implementation defined behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simultaneously iterating over and modifying an unordered\_set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981886/simultaneously-iterating-over-and-modifying-an-unordered-set)

Comment: @J.Schultke I think so, but I just wanted to confirm that my understanding is correct. Based on reading GManNickG's answer, it seems that even if we guarantee no rehashing, we could still iterate over the newly added elements?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I agree on both counts. But `std::unordered_set::reserve(N)` would guarantee that the unordered_set can store at least `N` numbers without rehashing correct? It guarantees it can store exactly `N` numbers if there are no collisions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not safe:

> On most cases, all iterators in the container remain valid after the insertion. The only exception being when the growth of the container forces a rehash. In this case, all iterators in the container are invalidated.

Sometimes it works, but I don't think this is enough for you!

Comment: I think the OP’s question is about whether the newly-added elements will be seen during the iterator traversal rather than about invalidation; they’ve used reserve such that a rehash won’t occur.

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes, that's correct. I am essentially asking the first part of my question based on assuming no rehashing occurs (due to the reserve statement and not exceeding the capacity)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the reserve.

Answer (score 0):

No. See [cppreference on `std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Cppreference.com has Iterator invalidation sections which describe when an iterator is invalidated. In the case of using `std::unordered_set`, inserting is not safe when a rehash occurs.

> Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`

And you can not know for certain whether inserting an element will cause that to happen.

In your example, you don't actually dereference the iterator, so why not loop over the size of the set?

```cpp
size_t limit = ht.size();
for (size_t i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think the OP’s question is about whether the newly-added elements will be seen during the iterator traversal rather than about invalidation; they’ve used reserve such that a rehash won’t occur.

Comment: Right, I understand all the iterators will be invalidated if rehashing occurs, but that's why I included the `reserve` and the associated comment.